# Got the Error "MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got the Error `MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms`.
I am using MongoDB Atlas.
I've tried changing `useUnifiedTopology`to false and my application doesn't crash, but I get the Error  `DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.`

The whole error message:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetWithPrimary',
    setName: 'atlas-lhb3t7-shard-0',
    maxSetVersion: 1,
    maxElectionId: 7fffffff0000000000000005,
    servers: Map {
      'wolfgangtest-shard-00-02.q8jpm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'wolfgangtest-shard-00-00.q8jpm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'wolfgangtest-shard-00-01.q8jpm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: 8
  }
}
```

My Mongoose code:

```
const dbOptions = {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            autoIndex: false,
            poolSize: 5,
            connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
            family: 4,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        };
        
        mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Wolfgang:christian13561z@wolfgangtest.q8jpm.mongodb.net/Wolfgang?retryWrites=true&w=majority', dbOptions);
        mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

How do i fix / bypass this?

Answer (score -1):

I think that there is a problem with your the connection URL from my experience with this kind of eror.Try
Try to use the same connecton URL in MongoDB compass if you use `windows` or `robomongo`.

You can also try to check :

[MongoDB connection error: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162342/mongodb-connection-error-mongotimeouterror-server-selection-timed-out-after-30)

[MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms while connecting to mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849515/mongotimeouterror-server-selection-timed-out-after-30000-ms-while-connecting-to)

[Server selection timed out after 10000 ms - Cannot connect Compass to mongoDB on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58160691/server-selection-timed-out-after-10000-ms-cannot-connect-compass-to-mongodb-on)

Comment: I did and I can connect to it just fine.